# How to change a FontA. icon to another one that has the same class name

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to a FontA. icon to another one that has the same class name.
What I tried was to add a class name named "active". Because there were only two icons to change back and forth, I thought HTML can show an icon I want by checking if the icon has "active". When the icon has "active", then I want to display it, but if not, I don't need to.
I think the problem is that they have the same class names.

[image]

The JS displayed this problem.
[image]

Also, there is only one way to hide an element?? Even if I added these below,

```
opacity: 0; 
visibility: hidden;
```

I saw blank space on a page. I didn't like it, so I wrote display: none; instead. But, I just wanna know there are some other ways to hide an element.
[image]

Comment: please post your code as text, not an image

Comment: it looks like you could perhaps over run the array you are looping thru

Comment: Not sure i understood what you mean with changing icon to another, becouse, i think, you can achieve this without using javascript. If you want to change icon on hover or "mousemove" why you didn't try to change the content of the element on hover so a new icon is shown. If im not so clear, tell me if what you want is just to change icon on hover.

Answer (score 0):

I won't understand your query well, But as much as I understand you want to change the icon of using js. 
It can be done using CSS only.
"Just use className.active to simply change the styling of the class Element. 'Eg:- .bi-list.active' It will change the style only on the class which has .active as its class item."
For CSS Only having Same Cl

```js
let icon1 = document.querySelectorAll('.bi')[0];
    let icon2 = document.querySelectorAll('.bi')[1];
    function changeIcon(){
      icon1.classList.toggle('active'); 
      icon2.classList.toggle('active'); 
    }
```

```css
i{
  display:none;
}
i.active{
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.7.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
</head>
<body>
<span>
<i class="bi bi-list active" onclick="changeIcon()"></i>
<i class="bi bi-x-lg" onclick="changeIcon()"></i>
</span>
</body>
```

ass name

 For Javascript:

```js
let icon = document.querySelector('.bi-list');
function ChangeIcon(){
  if(icon.classList.item(1) == "bi-list"){
    icon.classList.remove("bi-list");
    icon.classList.add("bi-x-lg");
  }
  else{
    icon.classList.remove("bi-x-lg");
    icon.classList.add("bi-list");
  }
}
```

```css
.menu .bi{
  color:blue;
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.7.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <span class="menu">
    <i class="bi bi-list" onclick="ChangeIcon()"></i>
      <!--<i class="bi bi-list active" onclick="ChangeIcon()"></i>
      <i class="bi bi-x-lg"></i>-->
    </span>
  </body>
</html>
```

And For the same classes, You can use document.querySelectorAll('.bi')[0] for accessing 1st element and ('.bi')[1} for accessing 2nd element.
If you want me to change anything in this code, Let me know!